# Proof that the number of pivots of a product of matrices is the minimum number of pivots of the matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

> Conjecture: Say we have matrices $A_1, A_2, ..., A_k$ where the
> corresponding number of pivots of the matrices are $p_1, p_2, ...,
> p_k$. Then the product $A_1\cdot A_2 \; \cdot \; ... \; \cdot \; A_k$
> has $\text{min}(p_1, p_2, ..., p_k)$ pivots.

I conjecture that the above is true because the image of a linear transformation can only have a lower dimension (or same dimension) than the dimension of the domain. Applying this reasoning inductively from the product of two matrices to $k$ matrices, the minimum number of pivots of the matrices is the same as the number of pivots of the product of the matrices.

I have tried a few examples, and the conjecture seems to hold. However, this reasoning is not rigorous, and I'm unable to prove this conjecture. Is the conjecture true, and if it is, how can we prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is true. I don't know the definition of a pivot, but if I remember correctly, the number of pivots is equal to the dimension of the image right ?

In this case consider the matrices correspinding to the linear maps $f(x,y) = (x,0)$ and $g(x,y) = (0,y)$. The number of pivots in each case should be 1, but if you compose the two function (multiply the matrices), you get the $0$ map (the $0$ matrix) which has $0$ pivots.